# How to import scss files properly in next-js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a nextJS project in which I am using sass with typescript. It all works in development environment but when I try to make a build version of my project it gives me this error.

[image]

This is my next.config.js

```
const config = {
  sassOptions: {
  cssModules: false,
},
  images: {
  domains: ["image.tmdb.org"],
 },
};
```

Comment: you have `cssModules: false,` so you can't do something like `import style from "./some.module.scss"`.

Comment: Even after changing it to true it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the way to work around this error.

**Step 1**

Create a file named `declaration.d.ts` on the root of project.

**Step 2**

```
declare module "*.scss" {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}
```

By default typescript does not knows any files other than .ts or .tsx so any other files which is imported in typescript file need to be first declared like this.